# How do I get one scroll down list to direct to different scroll down lists in the next col?

Tags: excel

I've got a list of 10 items in one scroll down in ColA and would like to make each of those items pointing to different scrolls downs in ColB.

Whatever you choose from ColA will give you a different scroll down option in ColB.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the above picture ComboBox1 is in A1, ComboBox2 is in B1.

In Combo1 you select the country and in Combo2 cities of the selected Combo1 Country.

Combo1 use data validation - List - source =D1:D3

In combo2 use data validation - List - and write in source the formula:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(A1;D1:D3;0);E1:E2;F1:F2;G1:G3)
```

Range E1:E2 contains cities of England, F1:F2 cities of France and G1:G3 cities of Portugal

Depending on your regional settings you may need to replace ";" by ","